# Getting data from OpenSearch into Grafana as a graph

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, opensearch

Please tell me, is it possible to receive or convert logs received from OpenSearch as a graph in Grafana?
The situation is as follows: there is Grafana, there is OpenSearch, connected as a data source in Grafana.
In OpenSearch I have a query: kubernetes.container_name:test AND 'Rejected by ' AND '400'
This OpenSearch query shows what I need.
Next, in Grafana I run the same query and get logs in the form of a table.
But how do I turn this table view into a graph?
I need a graph to show the number of records in OpenSearch according to a query.

Comment: Based on images [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-opensearch-datasource/) I assume there should be aggregation like count. Can you confirm this?